# Upgrading to .NET Core 2.0: PackageTargetFallback and AssetTargetFallback cannot be used together

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core, csproj, .net-core-2.0

When upgrading a project that is compiling and running fine on .NET Core 1.0 or 1.1, updating the target framework to .NET Core 2.0 (`netcoreapp2.0`) causes the build to fail with the following error:

```
 error NU1003: PackageTargetFallback and AssetTargetFallback cannot be used together. Remove PackageTargetFallback(deprecated) references from the project environment.
```

What is the reason for this error and how can it be resolved to make the project build again?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

In .NET Core 1.0 and 1.1, it was needed to set `PackageTargetFallback` when referencing packages that are known to work on .NET Core but don't officially support it - e.g. PCL libraries or libraries built for the legacy `dotnet` framework moniker.

Due to this, the project (`.csproj`, `.fsproj`, ...) will contain a line similar to:

```
<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
```

**In most cases, this line can simply be removed** and the project should build because .NET Core 2.0 already defines `AssetTargetFallback` to be `net461` - meaning that any NuGet package that is compatible with .NET Framework 4.6.1 or higher can be used without additional configuration.

If this introduces more build / restore errors, change the line to:

```
<AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</AssetTargetFallback>
```

The reason for the change is that `PackageTargetFallback` is considered deprecated and should be replaced with `AssetTargetFallback` which behaves only slightly different.

The breaking change in the tooling is that `netcoreapp2.0` and `netstandard2.0` automatically set `AssetTargetFallback` which conflicts with any `PackageTargetFallback` value defined in the project file.

Comment: Thanks, I opened the csproj in the editor and removed the <PackageTargetFallback> element entirely like you suggested and it worked just fine.

Comment: But what to do if there is no PackageTargetFallback in the project file?

Comment: @Dima so you get the error message in the question without any of `PackageTargetFallback` or `AssetTargetFallback` being defined in the project? Maybe some imported file? (e.g. `Directory.Build.props` in the folder hierarchy). Do consider opening a specific question for it or a GitHub issue somewhere. A binary log (`dotnet restore /bl` for example to get an `msbuild.binlog`) would help to diagnose

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, I get the exact error message, but have no Package TargetsFallback, even in the hierarchy. Will open a question.