# Errors after upgrading to netcoreapp2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I upgraded a ASP.NET Core solution from netcoreapp1.1 to netcoreapp2.0:

- I used the [upgrade guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/)
- installed the new SDK
- upgraded to VS2017 15.3.1
- removed all the old nuget packages, and replaced them with the new [metapackage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/)
- cleaned the solution, manually deleted all `bin` and `obj` directories, and rebuilt

I tried some tips I found such as:

- [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45569379/7059613) `PackageTargetFallback` / `AssetTargetFallback` which are not necessary
- [ensured](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/860) all csproj don't have `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` / `NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion`
- tried with and without `global.json` in solution root with `{ "sdk": { "version": "2.0.0" } }`
- deleted the `.vs` directory in the solution root
- cleared nuget package cache (Tools-Options-NuGet-Clear), and restored

However I get lots of errors like this:

> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

What more must I do?

Comment: I have the same question as you, Do you have global.json file in you folder?

Comment: Maybe your server or computer have several SDK version, and you should target the specific sdk version to 2.0.0 and restore the package.

Comment: @robert No `global.json` in my solution. I didn't uninstall the old SDKs, but the solution targets netcoreapp2.0 (I followed the upgrade guide). Please let me know if you solve this problem somehow.

Comment: I solved this question by add global.json in my project folder like that `{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.0.0"
  }
}`

Comment: Do you have reference to the` NETStandard.Library.NETFramework ` ?

Comment: @irshadjm Don't think so... where is that specified? In a csproj?

Comment: check in your reference or in packages

Comment: @irshadjm Nope it looks like that is for .net framework, not for netcoreapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we had a `Directory.Build.props` file in the solution root, which had common msbuild stuff for all projects in the solution.

That file referenced `netcoreapp1.1`. Once I updated it to `netcoreapp2.0`, everything worked.